# jquery form validation not working after rule added

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have added rule for the control. but still error not showing after form validation. After click I have validate input box and check empty string. if empty string show error otherwise call ajax method. but error never showing.

### Edit:

@Sparky suggested. I am updating my post. I am loading input box and anchor tag after DOM loaded. then I added validation rule for `CompanyName` control. And also checking validation in `<a>` click and it is false. but still error text is not showing.

html

```
<form action="/Address/AddAddress" id="frmAddress" method="post" name="frmAddress" novalidate="novalidate">
   <div id="AddEditAddressPlaceHolder>
           <input name="CompanyName" class="SPE-Formcontrol" id="CompanyName" type="text" value="">

          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success" onclick="javascript: submitcompanyfind();">Find Company</a>
```

javascript

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'AddressTypesListChange',
                type: "Get",
                data: { 'addressType': $("#AddressTypeslist").val()},
                cache: false,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#AddEditAddressPlaceHolder').html(data);
                   $("#frmAddress").validate({
                        errorClass: "validationError"
                    });
                    $("#CompanyName").rules("add", {required: true,messages: {required: "Required"}});

                }
            });


 function submitcompanyfind() {
      $("#frmAddress").validate();
      alert($("#frmAddress").valid()); // it is false but no error showing.
     if ($('#CompanyName').val() !="") {
         $.ajax({
             url: 'FindCompanyList',
             type: 'Post',
             data: $("#frmAddress").serialize(),
             success: function(data) {
                 var count = Object.keys(data).length;
                 //load the company table rows
                 LoadCompanyList(data);

                 $("#hdnDivComapnyfinder").show();
             },
             error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

             }
         });
     }

 }
```

After page load html source looks like this.

```
<div id="AddEditAddressPlaceHolder">
        <input name="CompanyName" class="SPE-Formcontrol 
        input-validation-error" id="CompanyName" type="text" 
       value="" aria-required="true" 
       aria-describedby="CompanyName-error" aria-invalid="true">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** the following answer was for the OP's [original version of his question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30649543/3).

---

The problem is caused by incorrectly calling the `.validate()` method inside of a function that's triggered on the click of the submit button.

The `.validate()` method is the initialization of the plugin and only gets called once on DOM ready.

The other problem is the location of your `ajax()`.  [The `.ajax()` only belongs inside the `submitHandler` option of the `.validate()` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org//validate/#submithandler).

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#frmAddress").validate({
         rules: {
             CompanyName: {
                 required: true
             }
         },
         messages: {
             CompanyName: {
                 required: "Required"
             }
         },
         errorClass: "validationError",
         submitHandler: function(form) {
             // your ajax function here,
             return false;
         }
     });

});
```

Don't forget to remove your inline JavaScript from the "submit button"...

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Find Company</a>
```

Ans since you're using an anchor tag instead of a real `type="submit"` `button` or `input`, you'll need to write a `click` handler function that triggers validation by programmatically calling submit...

```
$('#frmAddress a').on('click', function() {
    $('#frmAddress').submit();
});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/3nsapjrh/**

---

You do not need to put the `novalidate="novalidate"` attribute within your `<form>` tag.  The plugin already dynamically does this for you.

Comment: I tried as you said. In my case after submit the form it refreshing the page (reload the page).

Comment: @James123, [as you can see in my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3nsapjrh/), that is absolutely impossible.  Check your console for errors.

Comment: one more thing. I am loading input and <a> link from other ajax. So it is not available when DOM loads. ex: ` success: function (data) {
                    $('#AddEditAddressPlaceHolder').html(data);`

Comment: @James123, that's not part of your original question at all.  However, you'd simply need to adjust the `click` handler to delegate the event to elements created in the future.  Refer to the `.on()` documentation.

Comment: @James123, that's great that you've corrected your OP.  However, your OP is nothing like it was originally and you've rendered my answer completely disconnected from your question.

Comment: @James123, again, the `.validate()` method is only for **INITIALIZING** the plugin on your form.  It should not be called within the click handler for your submit.  And the `ajax()` used for submitting the form **BELONGS INSIDE** the `submitHandler` option.

Answer (score 1):

**Second answer:**  posted in response to edited OP.

I'm not going to include specific code to a question that has been changed so radically since it was originally posted.  Instead, I'll review the critical points that need to be followed in this situation...

1. Load the page, including the relevant plugins.
2. Trigger the `ajax()` that loads and/or creates the form and/or all of its input fields.  *{form fully exists on the page now}*
3. Call `.validate()` to **initialize** the plugin on the newly created form.  You would not need the `.rules()` method since you can declare the rules within `.validate()` at this point.

**NOTES**:

- Once `.validate()` is called, you cannot call it again for any reason.  You can only use `rules()` method to dynamically add/remove rules.
- You would never need any inline JavaScript.  **Remove** your  `onclick="javascript: submitcompanyfind();"` and the `submitcompanyfind()` function.
- When you're not using a `type="submit"`, you need to construct a simple `click` handler to trigger a `.submit()`.   If the anchor tag does not yet exist when you call the `click` handler, you simply need to ["delegate" it](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

  ```
  $('#frmAddress').on('click', 'a', function() {
      $(this).submit();
  });
  ```
- If you're submitting the form with `ajax()`, then you must put that `ajax()` function [within the `submitHandler` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org//validate/#submithandler) of the `.validate()` method.

Comment: can I change `submitHandler: function (form)` dynamically. based on condition

Comment: @James123, once you call `validate()` it cannot be called again, so you cannot add or change any option.  You can only add/remove rules via `rules()` method.

Comment: I did ` success: function(data) {
                    $('#AddEditAddressPlaceHolder').html(data);
                    $("#frmAddress").validate({rules: { CompanyName: { required: true } },.. }` . But this is not working.

Comment: @James123, I'm not sure how you expect me to help you when you're not telling me anything meaningful.  If you've followed the guidelines, then that code would be working.  Are you calling `.validate()` more than once?  Does the form exist when you're calling `.validate()`?